# Delphi low-level machine parameter access

Tags: delphi, parameters, low-level, measurement

There are many very low-level parameters measured by PCs and their processors (e.g. core temperatures, fan-speeds, voltage levels at various parts of the motherboard and processor internals) which are available and displayed by the BIOS, and by some aaplication programs. How does one access these low-level (real-time) data via Delphi? Is there a library? Is there a Windows API?

Answer (score 1):

See [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx).

[update]
To use WMI in Delphi, you need to import "Microsoft WMI Scripting vx.x Library" in Delphi IDE.
See [this](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3118.asp?SK=) for example.

Comment: can't find any references to WMI anywhere in Delphi doc. Is this a supported Windows API in Delphi?

Comment: WMI is provided by Windows. However since it's implemented as ActiveX/COM, you can use it in Delphi. See my updates.

Answer (score 1):

[RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) did a nice [series of articles on using WMI with Delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/category/wmi/).

He even created a [WMI Delphi source code generator](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/a-new-project-delphi-object-pascal-wmi-class-code-generator/).